# Integração Cielo By Page Loja

Tags: php

Estou com um problema o qual já tentei resolver de diversas maneiras, mas até agora nada e por isso resolvi recorrer aqui.

Estou implementando o *Gateway* de pagamento da Cielo, a solução *By Page* Loja, onde o usuário realiza a inserção dos dados de pagamento na minha própria loja, e depois é gerado um XML para o Cielo, e todo o processo ocorre.

Baixei o Kit de integração da Cielo, onde vem com uma loja modelo, e ativei a mesma no meu ambiente de desenvolvimento, e funcionou perfeitamente, tive apenas que alterar as seguintes linhas:

```
curl_setopt($sessao_curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() ."/ssl/VeriSignClass3PublicPrimaryCertificationAuthority-G5.CRT");
curl_setopt($sessao_curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1);
```

A primeira linha informa onde o certificado, fornecido pela Cielo, encontra-se em meu diretório e a segunda linha a versão do certificado.

### Situação

Quando rodo o sistema na minha máquina, chamando o ambiente de homologação da Cielo, todo o processo ocorre corretamente e sem problema algum.

Porém, quando coloco este código no ambiente de homologação do cliente, e tento processar, o sistema cria o XML corretamente, mas no momento de realizar a conexão com o ambiente da Cielo, retorna o seguinte erro

```
Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

Ou seja, o sistema não consegue estabelecer a conexão com o servidor da Cielo para enviar o XML, o problema é que não sei se é no momento do envio ou do retorno do XML.

Gostaria de saber se alguém já passou por este problema, se existe algum tipo de liberação necessário para fazer no servidor, versão de PHP, etc.

Segue abaixo o código que realiza a conexão com o servidor da Cielo.

```php
require 'errorHandling.php';
require_once 'pedido.php';
require_once 'logger.php';

define('VERSAO', "1.1.0");

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["pedidos"]))
{
    $_SESSION["pedidos"] = new ArrayObject();
}

// CONSTANTES
define("ENDERECO_BASE", "https://qasecommerce.cielo.com.br");
define("ENDERECO", ENDERECO_BASE."/servicos/ecommwsec.do");

define("LOJA", "0000000");
define("LOJA_CHAVE", "xxxxxxxxx");
define("CIELO", "0000000");
define("CIELO_CHAVE", "xxxxxxxxx");


// Envia requisição
function httprequest($paEndereco, $paPost){

    $sessao_curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($sessao_curl, CURLOPT_URL, $paEndereco);

    curl_setopt($sessao_curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);

    //  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER
    //  verifica a validade do certificado
    curl_setopt($sessao_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);

    //  CURLOPPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST
    //  verifica se a identidade do servidor bate com aquela informada no certificado
    curl_setopt($sessao_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

    //  CURLOPT_SSL_CAINFO
    //  informa a localização do certificado para verificação com o peer
    curl_setopt($sessao_curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() ."/ssl/VeriSignClass3PublicPrimaryCertificationAuthority-G5.CRT");
    curl_setopt($sessao_curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1);

    //  CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT
    //  o tempo em segundos de espera para obter uma conexão
    curl_setopt($sessao_curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);

    //  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT
    //  o tempo máximo em segundos de espera para a execução da requisição (curl_exec)
    curl_setopt($sessao_curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);

    //  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER
    //  TRUE para curl_exec retornar uma string de resultado em caso de sucesso, ao
    //  invés de imprimir o resultado na tela. Retorna FALSE se há problemas na requisição
    curl_setopt($sessao_curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($sessao_curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($sessao_curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $paPost );

    $resultado = curl_exec($sessao_curl);

    if (!$resultado) 
        $curl_error = curl_error($sessao_curl); // Capturo o erro ANTES de fechar

    curl_close($sessao_curl);

    if (!$resultado) 
        echo "<br><font size=6>" . $curl_error ;

    if ($resultado)
    {
        return $resultado;
    }
    else
    {
        return curl_error($sessao_curl);
    }
}

// Monta URL de retorno
function ReturnURL()
{
    $pageURL = 'http';

    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] == 443) // protocolo https
    {
        $pageURL .= 's';
    }
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80")
    {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } else {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]. substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 0);
    }
    // ALTERNATIVA PARA SERVER_NAME -> HOST_HTTP

    $file = substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1);

    $ReturnURL = str_replace($file, "retorno.php", $pageURL);

    return $ReturnURL;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de muito tempo e muitas pesquisa identifiquei que o problema estava nesta linha

```
CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3
```

Em um comunicado feito inclusive pelo Pay Pal o mesmo informou que as pessoas que estivessem utilizando esta linha de código desta maneira deveriam alterar para a linha abaixo

```
CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4
```

Pelo que eu entendi o código 3 valida o seu certificado utilizando a última regra de validação existente e me parece que a nova versão que foi lançada ocorria algum tipo de problema, que não conseguia validar o certificado e retornava como certificado inválido.

Devido a isso eles solicitaram para utilizar o código 4, que faz a checagem mas utilizando a última versão de validação estável do sistema, ou seja, a versão anterior do código de validação.

Ao fazer isto o meu sistema começou a funcionar perfeitamente, sem problema algum e também passou pela homologação da Cielo sem problemas.

Vai a dica para quem estiver ou tenha passado por este problema.

Espero ter ajudado

Abs

Answer (score 3):

Já tinha percebido esta questão e realizado esta alteração, mas mesmo assim não resolveu.

Pesquisando muito na internet, encontrei um post de integração com o Pay Pal que informaram, que esta linha de código:

```
curl_setopt($sessao_curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
```

devido a um bug no Poodle (acho que é isso), deveria ser alterada para

```
    curl_setopt($sessao_curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4);
```

Realizei esta alteração e o problema parou de ocorrer.

Em pesquisa sobre esta alteração informaram que existe um bug na nova versão de validação do SSL, por isto deve-se utilizar o valor 4, porque com este valor o sistema não utiliza a última versão de avaliação do certificado, mas sim a anterior (acho que é isso)

Fiz esta alteração e agora está funcionando

Pode ser que esta informação ajude quem tiver o mesmo problema

Obrigado pela resposta

Abs

Answer (score 1):

Passei pelo mesmo problema, no meu caso resolvi renomeando o arquivo SSL que vem no kit de integração da Cielo, pois na definição do cURL você está utilizando o formato que vem no exemplo da Cielo, que é:

```
curl_setopt($sessao_curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() ."/ssl/VeriSignClass3PublicPrimaryCertificationAuthority-G5.CRT");
```

Porém no kit de integração este arquivo vem com o nome `VERISI~1.CRT` ao invés de `VeriSignClass3PublicPrimaryCertificationAuthority-G5.CRT`

Fazendo esta atualização as conexões passaram a ser realizadas normalmente no meu caso. Espero que ajude!